# Why is the Mother Wolf named Nisha in Netflix's Mowgli?

Tags: character, mowgli-legend-of-the-jungle

I'm watching *Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle* on Netflix, and I noticed that the Mother Wolf who adopts Mowgli is named "Nisha."  Best I can tell, Kipling's book names her [Raksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raksha_%28The_Jungle_Book%29), as in [this exchange between her and Shere Khan](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/236/236-h/236-h.htm#link2H_4_0001):

> “Ye choose and ye do not choose! What talk is this of choosing? By the
>   bull that I killed, am I to stand nosing into your dog’s den for my
>   fair dues? It is I, Shere Khan, who speak!”
>
> The tiger’s roar filled the cave with thunder. Mother Wolf shook
>   herself clear of the cubs and sprang forward, her eyes, like two green
>   moons in the darkness, facing the blazing eyes of Shere Khan.
>
> “And it is I, Raksha [The Demon], who answers. The man’s cub is mine,
>   Lungri—mine to me! He shall not be killed. He shall live to run with
>   the Pack and to hunt with the Pack; and in the end, look you, hunter
>   of little naked cubs—frog-eater—fish-killer—he shall hunt thee! Now
>   get hence, or by the Sambhur that I killed (I eat no starved cattle),
>   back thou goest to thy mother, burned beast of the jungle, lamer than
>   ever thou camest into the world! Go!”

As far as I can tell, "Nisha" doesn't appear in either book by Kipling.

How and why did they pick this name instead of Raksha?

Comment: Good Q! I went to the film's wiki page and clicked on one Nisha link and it tool me to Raksha character page! I found out that Nisha means "night" and that in at least one other adaptation, the character is renamed (something else) to reflect a slightly different role from the original. I don't know if that is the same reasoning here or not, but that is where I am leaning.

Comment: Interesting. "Nisha" is indeed a fairly common name in India meaning "night." Which one was the other adaptation? But best I can tall, the Mother Wolf's role here is pretty standard - there's not much difference in character or story, except perhaps she's not as assertive as the dialogue in the question would suggest.

Comment: Fun fact is Indian dub is played by Madhuri who played a famous character called Nisha before too

Comment: From the Rashka wikipage: "In the anime Jungle Book Shonen Mowgli, Raksha appears like in the book, except she is renamed Luri, has a more important role in the story line, and becomes the eventual leader of the wolf pack." I'm not sure what Luri means and/or if it might be a variation of Laurie? Anyways still doing some research, but I find @AnkitSharma comment interesting!!

Comment: @DarthLocke ah, I remember watching the dubbed version of that ages ago. Oddly enough, the Hindi dub renamed Luri to Chameli (and Alexander to Moti) - if you can understand some Hindi, see [this video](https://youtu.be/xVkj9a-tbpo?t=1111).

Comment: Vihaan also a new name..